# Dropping an item from a DataFrame vector column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a DataFrame with a single column `'value'`. I want to split it by space, remove the first item from the split, and recombine the remaining items into a vector column.

It's very easy to do with a UDF or by converting to and from RDD, but I want to use only DataFrame API for performance and code simplicity reasons.

The best I could do was this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([['10 11 12']], ['value'])
df_split = df.select(F.split('value', ' ').alias('split'))
n = df_split.select(F.size(df_split['split'])).collect()[0][0]
df_columns = df_split.select([F.col('split')[i].astype('int').alias(str(i)) for i in range(1, n)])
v = VectorAssembler(inputCols=[str(i) for i in range(1, n)], outputCol='result')
df_result = v.transform(df_columns).select('result')
```

It works, but requires an extra action (to get the size of the column after split), and a lot of code for such a simple task. Is there a simpler way of doing this?

In addition, `VectorAssembler` won't work for non-numeric types.

Spark 2.0.0, python 3.5.

Comment: Does it really work? Vector assembler doesn't accept string columns, does it?

Comment: @zero323 no , I forgot the .astype() converting string to numbers. I'll edit it, thanks.